# Kibana not accessible on remote machine

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, remote-access, openvpn

I have docker running on a remote linux machine and I want to start elasticsearch and kibana services there.

I use the following commands:

```
docker network create elastic
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2
docker run --name elasticsearch --net elastic -m 4GB -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2

docker pull docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.6.2
docker run --name kibana --net elastic -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.6.2
```

Both seem to be running fine and the kibana service shows that "Kibana has not been configured". Go to http://0.0.0.0:5601/?code=xxxxxx to get started."

Now the problem is that I want to use this link in the browser of another machine which has windows. I tried putting in different IP addresses from "ifconfig" hosts and also the IP address I use to ssh connect to the remote machine, but the browser link shows no response. How do I find the correct IP address to use in the browser of another machine to see the elasticsearch/kibana UI there?

Maybe one thing to also mention here is that I am running a VPN (with its own public ip and port) through openVPN and only then when I use the ssh connection (with a different ip address/port), a connection is established.
I also tried going through the firewall rules if that might be the problem but there don't seem to be any rules installed on the remote machine.

Comment: ```-e "server.host=0.0.0.0"``` can help

docker run --name kibana --net elastic -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.6.2 -e "server.host=0.0.0.0"

Comment: @MusabDogan running this gives "[FATAL tini (6)] exec -e failed: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reaching the kibana from another server you can use the following option.

1- create a token for kibana

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
```

2- stop the kibana

3- run the following command, it will modify kibana.yml.

```
sudo /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-setup --enrollment-token <enrollment-token>
```

more details:

https://medium.com/@musabdogan/installing-elasticsearch-cluster-multi-node-cluster-with-elasticsearch-version-8-631ddc774648

Comment: Good idea, but the problem will remain, how to access Kibana from that remote Linux box? An SSH tunnel seems to be one option

Comment: Not sure about how to connect to the remote :/

Comment: Should be as simple as `ssh user@a.b.c.d -L5601:a.b.c.d:5601` where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address of the remote Linux host where you can login via SSH. When that tunnel is open, you can then access Kibana from your localhost via `http://localhost:5601`

Comment: @Val this directory doesnt exist: /usr/share/kibana
also, the ssh tunnel is not accepting the password I enter for the simple ssh connection to the remote machine

Comment: because I have a specific port for which I connect